# Save images in a loop with variable file names?

Tags: string, matlab, numbers, save-as

I have a loop as such:

```
for n = 1:6
figure
plot()
saveas(gcf,'figure', 'jpeg')
end
```

This however just keeps saving the figures over each other since they all have the same name. What I need is to make it so the name is 'figure_n' where n is the iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [*`num2str`*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html)

```
saveas(gcf, ['figure_' num2str(n) ], 'jpeg') ;
```

Comment: simple and works! Side question, how would I change that line of code to save all the images to a folder on my desktop?

Comment: @user3145111 Something like `saveas(gcf, ['C:\path_to_folder_on_desktop\' 'figure_' num2str(n) ], 'jpeg') ;`

Answer (score 2):

```
for i=1:6
    % construct the filename for this loop - this would be `str1` in your example
    file_name = sprintf('picture_%i.jpeg', i);
    % or:
    file_name = strcat('picture_', num2str(i), '.jpeg');
    % call the function with this filename:
    saveas(gcf,'file_name','jpeg') 
end
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like to use the '%02i' option in the `sprintf`, so the files are numbered 01,02,... and not 1,2,... This way if you have more then 10 files, they get sorted correctly when you sort the folder by file name.